# Magento get product ID in custom module block on product detail page

Tags: php, magento

I have a custom module with a block which shows a form inside the product detail page. I need to retrieve the product ID for the currently viewed product inside this block. Everything else is working.

Other answers suggested trying:

```
$this->getProduct()->getId(); // or
Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
```

The former returned an error. Using this one inside the product detail template is working fine. I understand that's because getProduct() is not a method for the block.

The latter is always returning null.

If anyone could help me, that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The custom block layout.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info">
                <block
                    type="s148_interestnotification/form"
                    name="interest_notification"
                    before="-"
                    template="s148_interestnotification/index.phtml"
                ></block>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your custom block is extending this class

> Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View

you would be easily able to use : **$this->getProduct()**

Comment: It's already extending Mage_Core_Block_Template, when i swap that with what you are suggesting i get "Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on null in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php"

Comment: I can't guess what is the problem now , I've updated the class name , can you please try the new class name above

Comment: Now i'm not recieving an error, but $this->getProduct() returns null. I've updated my question with some info on the block layout.xml, not sure if its relavent, but it will give you an idea where it is placed.

Comment: Sorry, i failed while testing this. The first answer with "Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View" did work! Could you change back your answer? Thanks for all your troubles :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$collection = Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Viewed')->getItemsCollection();
```

Comment: This seems to be returning something, i can't really find out what it is though. It doesn't seem to be the current product.